# Polymorphic has_many association for class which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base through parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

A'm using [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem for history tracking in my Rails 4 project. And for purposes of the application I had to create custom paper trail version class as described [here](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#custom-version-classes).

```
class PostVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  self.table_name = :versions
end
```

Also I have `Comment` model which can be attached to any other model through polymorphic `belongs_to`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now I want to add comments to `PostVersion` instances and do the following:

```
class PostVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  self.table_name = :versions
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

It would work great if I hadn't got this `PostVersion < PaperTrail::Version` inheritance. But in this case we'll see that inside `PostVersion` instance `commentable_type` would be set to `"PaperTrail::Version"` not `"PostVersion"`:

```
$ rails console
[1] pry(main)> PostVersion.last.comments.create(message: 'bla')
=> #<Comment id: 1, message: "bla", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "PaperTrail::Version">
```

How to make `commentable_type` to be aware of my inheritance chain of `PostVersion`?

Comment: Ended up with creating plain old ruby methods for this:
`def comments<< (comment); Comment.create(...); end`
`def comments; Comment.where(...); end`